# Selecionar somente uma coluna de tabela HTML mudando seu valor com Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tabela-html

Parece ser algo simples mas que me prendeu por um tempinho. Eu preciso pegar o valor das colunas 'Valor Final' para se esse valor for maior que 5000, eu mudo a cor do valor da coluna 'Status'.

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Produtividade</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <figure>
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo em Gráfico">
        </figure>
        <h1>Tabela de Produtividade Anual</h1>
    </header>
    <main>
        <table id="tabela">
            <thead>
                <th>Colaborador</th>
                <th>Soldo</th>
                <th>Comissão</th>
                <th>Valor Final</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Jonas</td>
                    <td>800</td>
                    <td>200</td>
                    <td class="valorFinal">1500</td>
                    <td class="status">Positivo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Eládio</td>
                    <td>900</td>
                    <td>300</td>
                    <td class="valorFinal">3600</td>
                    <td class="status">Positivo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Israel</td>
                    <td>1000</td>
                    <td>400</td>
                    <td class="valorFinal">5200</td>
                    <td class="status">Positivo</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </main>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Código Javascript:

```
//Chamadas de Funções

qtdLinhasTabela()

//Funções
function determinarStatus(valorFinal) {
    const colunaStatus = document.querySelector(".status")

    if(Number.parseInt(valorFinal) > 5000) {
        colunaStatus.style.color = 'green' 
    } else {
        colunaStatus.style.color = 'red'
    }
}

function qtdLinhasTabela() {
    let tabela = document.querySelector('#tabela')
    let linha = tabela.getElementsByTagName('tr')

    for(var i = 1; i <= linha.length; i++) {
        celula = linha[i].getElementsByTagName('td')
        colunaValorFinal = document.write(celula[3].innerText + "<br>")
        determinarStatus(colunaValorFinal)
    }
}
```

```
Já procurei nos forums mas não encontrei um exemplo semelhante. A maioria usa jQuery, mas como  meu objetivo é estudar o assunto(pois sou iniciante), preciso fazer com Javascript puro. Agradeço desde já a ajuda de todos.
```

Comment: Se você é iniciante, uma dica: use nomes significativos para as funções. Isso facilita a manutenção do seu código por você e por terceiros. Eu tive que ler a função ```qtdLinhasTabela()``` para entender o que ela faz. Você poderia chamar de ```iterarLinhasTabela()```, ou algo assim. Além disso, as variáveis ```linhas``` e ```celulas``` receberão uma HTMLCollection de valores, mesmo que a tabela só tenha uma linha. Por isso, é bom colocar o nome no plural, "linhas" e "celulas", para lembrar que é um valor coletivo (mesmo que possam conter um item só).

Comment: A contagem de objetos nos tipos iteráveis de javascript começa do 0, portanto, seu ```for``` deve começar do 0 (ou começar do 1 para ignorar a linha-cabeçalho, isso se a sua seleção de ```linhas``` já não houver selecionado corretamente as linhas do ```tbody```) até ```linhas.length - 1```. Você pode fazer ```for(var i = 0; i < linha.length; i++) {```.

Comment: O document.write provavelmente terá efeitos diferentes do que você deseja. A linha colunaValorFinal = document.write(celula[3].innerText + "<br>") substituiria o conteúdo do documento inteiro pelo texto da célula. Todavia, como não existe celula[3] (esta seria a quarta célula, pois começa a contar em celula[0]), deve retornar um erro no console de "lendo propriedade innerText de undefined", ou algo assim. O correto seria você pegar uma referência à célula: celulaValorFinal = celulas[2], e passar essa referência para a função determinarStatus.

Comment: Mas isso também é contraproducente. É melhor você passar a ```linhaAtual``` inteira para a função que verifica o valor e, se for o caso, muda o status. Lá você testa o valor (que está na célula ```linhaAtual.querySelector(".valorFinal")``` e aplica o estilo que quiser na célula ```linhaAtual.querySelector(".status")```.

Comment: Quanto a essa classe "valorFinal", o padrão convencionado para CSS costuma usar kebab case, e não camel case, então o mais comum é o formato "valor-final" nas classes CSS, ainda que seja valorFinal nas variáveis javascript (mas isso é só uma convenção, não vai quebrar seu código).

Comment: Em síntese: estudar bastante mais, e de forma mais estruturada.

Comment: Olá @CésarRodriguez! Muito Obrigado pelos comentários, vejo que aqui serei muito bem recebido pra tirar dúvidas e quem sabe um dia ajudar outros no futuro. Peço desculpas desde já pelo código mal organizado, pois o DOCUMENT.WRITE em questão foi apenas para me mostrar o que a função que eu fiz estava retornando. E quanto aos nomes, realmente durante mais de 6 horas(SIM!! mais de 6 horas e não obtive o resultado desejado no dia em quastão kkkk), eu acabei deixando nomes antigos de funções fracassadas anteriores. Esse código ficou bagunçado, mas logo abaixo vou explicar melhor do que se trata.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez eu vou explicar meu obejtivo e o que aconteceu pra que fique mais claro, vou tentar também melhorar o código em questão pra ser usado por alguém futuramente com a mesma dúvida. O meu objetivo com esse código foi de pegar o valor final da tabela e simplesmente verificar se esse valor é maior que 5000. Se for maior, colore de Verde, senão colore de vermelho. O problema(e é aí onde entra o DOCUMENT.WRITE) é que ela retornou todos os valores finar da tabela em uma única linha, todo aninhados, o que tornou o valor gigante e não funcionando.

Comment: @CésarRodriguez também o loop executou a função apenas na primeira linha. Não sei se isso tem a ver com o fato dos valores estarem todos aninhados de uma vez só. No Resumo, a função leu a tabela, mas não consegui que ele executasse o valor final de linha por linha na função, uma de cada vez para tratar o valor e fazer a mudança necessária no Status na tabela.

Comment: Quanto ao ```document.write(...)```, o que normalmente se usa para verificar valores é o ```console.log(...)```, e a coisa a ser logada vai aparecer no console. Quanto às minhas sugestões, você aplicou alguma? Vá testando.

Comment: Apliquei. Vou repostar o código e mostrar como ficou até agora logo abaixo.

Answer (score 0):

Companheiros quero encerrar este Tópico pois consegui resolver meu problema. Acontece que eu não estava indicando o **INDICE** na função **determinarStatus**, logo, o javascript só editava a primeira linha.
Como o meu objetivo era de fazer a edição somente em uma coluna, com o índice que determina em qual linha a função está tratando, consegui percorrer e editar célula por célula da coluna **Status**. Vou compartilhar o código completo aqui abaixo com as mudanças que vocês me indicaram e também para caso alguém tenha uma dúvida futura. Se quiserem me dar mais dicas de como organizar meu código(deixar ele mais limpo e de acordo com os padrões usados nas empresas), por favor me digam! Desde já muito obrigado e fiquem com Deus!

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Produtividade</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Tabela de Produtividade Anual</h1>
        </header>
        <main>
            <table id="tabela">
                <thead>
                    <th>Colaborador</th>
                    <th>Soldo</th>
                    <th>Comissão</th>
                    <th>Valor Final</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jonas</td>
                        <td>800</td>
                        <td>200</td>
                        <td class="valorFinal">1500</td>
                        <td class="status"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Eládio</td>
                        <td>900</td>
                        <td>300</td>
                        <td class="valorFinal">5001</td>
                        <td class="status"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Israel</td>
                        <td>1000</td>
                        <td>400</td>
                        <td class="valorFinal">5200</td>
                        <td class="status"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </main>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
    /*Toda a Página*/
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background-color: #e9e9ef;
    }

    /*Cabeçalho*/
    header{
        width: 100%;
    }
    header h1 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

    /*Conteúdo Principal*/
    main {
        width: 100%;
    }
    main table {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 80%;
        text-align: center;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    main table th{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #373535;
    }
    main table tr{
        border-bottom: 1px solid #373535;
        height: 30px;
    }
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    //Chamadas de Funções
    logicaDeterminarStatus()

    //Funções
    function determinarStatus(valorFinal, indiceLinha) {
        const tabela = document.querySelector('#tabela')
        const linhas = tabela.getElementsByTagName('tr')[indiceLinha]
        const colunaStatus = linhas.querySelector(".status")

        if(Number.parseInt(valorFinal) > 5000) {
            colunaStatus.style.color = 'green' 
            colunaStatus.innerText = 'POSITIVO'
        } else {
            colunaStatus.style.color = 'red'
            colunaStatus.innerText = 'NEGATIVO'
        }
    }

    function logicaDeterminarStatus() {
        const tabela = document.querySelector('#tabela')
        const linhas = tabela.getElementsByTagName('tr')
        let vetorRecebeValorFinal = [null]

        for(var i = 1; i < linhas.length; i++) {
            celulas = linhas[i].getElementsByTagName('td')
            vetorRecebeValorFinal.push(celulas[3].innerText)
            determinarStatus(vetorRecebeValorFinal[i], i)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

para que seu código faça o que você descreveu, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

Sua função qtdLinhasTabela() pode ficar desta maneira:

```js
function qtdLinhasTabela() {
    let tabela = document.querySelector('#tabela')
    let linha = tabela.getElementsByTagName('tr')

    for(var i = 1; i < linha.length; i++) {
        celula = linha[i].getElementsByTagName('td')
        determinarStatus(celula[3])
    }
}
```

E a sua função determinarStatus() pode ficar assim:

```js
function determinarStatus(valorFinal) {
    if(Number.parseInt(valorFinal.innerText) > 5000) {
        valorFinal.style.color = 'green' 
    } else {
        valorFinal.style.color = 'red'
    }
}
```

Se você usou o document.write() com o objetivo de te auxiliar em algo para mudar a cor dos valores, na verdade isso não vai ajudar, então você não precisaria dessa linha. Já o argumento que você envia para a função determinarStatus() deve ser o 'td', porque lá nessa função você altera o estilo inline do próprio 'td', então é ele quem deve ser enviado.

Falando ainda da função determinarStatus(valorFinal), como você já vai estar recebendo o 'td' com o valor, você não precisa selecionar novamente, basta fazer o seu if e atribuir os estilos, afinal você já tem ali o elemento que vai ser manipulado.

Tudo o que foi comentado pelo César você deve levar em consideração, e apesar de serem coisas que vão sendo aprendidas e praticadas com o tempo, vá absorvendo as forem possíveis, mas tudo dentro do seu tempo.

Comment: Olá @Ricardo! Muito obrigado pela sua resposta. o código que eu fiz ficou meio desorganizado por alguns motivos que expliquei ao @Cesar Rodriguez logo acima. Abaixo vou explicar melhor o meu objetivo com esse código pra tentar reformular minha dúvida, pois no dia em questão eu estava sem pensar direito depois de um bom tempo tentando resolver o problema.

Comment: eu comente meu objetivo e o problema para o Cesar, agradeço se puder me ajudar também com essa dúvida.